# regular expression for decimal issue

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I used decimal regular expression `\d{1,5}([.]\d{1,2})?|[.]\d{1,2}`.

It works fine in normal scenario. But when I type value like `55.123` and remove `123` with back space and just leave value as `55.` it shows a validation/error message.

I want to restrict to show message in this case (I mean want to have my validation message not to appear for "55." as this is valid value for me )

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking.  Are you trying to fix some c# code ? Or are you looking for a regular expression?  Please post the code you've written and errors you are getting.

Comment: but a value like `55.` cannot be a valid value , but `55.0` can be!

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern

`\d+\.?\d*`

which says

- `\d+` that atleast 1 digit preceding is needed but more could follow.
- `\.?` with an **optional** period.
- `\d*` followed by 0 or more digits.

If the pattern needs to not have any possible whitespace, enclose it with the beginning of line/end of line anchors such as

`^\d+\.?\d*$`